How to improve a query that runs slow when a the parameter of a criteria changes from a word of 4 characters to 11 characters
Let's say we have following structure for two tables:
Table: device_usage



Column Name
Column Type





cost
number



device_id
uuid
foreign key - tight relationship to devices table



Table: devices



Column Name
Column Type





organization_id
uuid
loose relationship to scope devices for organizations


type
varchar
used as an enum field and the value controlled at the application level - possible values: water, electricity, gas



The query that I'm struggled with is as followed:
select
  device_usage.*
from
  device_usage
inner join
  devices on device_usage.device_id = devices.id
where
  devices.organization_id = 'some_uuid'
  and devices.type = 'water'
limit 10

When I run the query with devices.type = 'water', it returns 10 records in 1 second. However, when I change it to devices.type = 'electricity', it takes around 15 seconds to fetch the same number of records.
Btw there are over 5 millions of records in the device_usage table.
So the questions are:

Why there is a big difference in terms of performance when water changes to electricity?
Is using postgres enum for the devices.type column instead of varchar going to improve the performance?
What combination of indices is suggested for this structure?

I added an index for divice_usage.device_id column and it improved the query performance but it didn't fix the issue with the slow run on electricity parameter.
explian anlyze when using water:
"Limit  (cost=0.29..100.36 rows=10 width=313) (actual time=0.218..0.227 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..271813.98 rows=27163 width=313) (actual time=0.217..0.225 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on device_usage (cost=0.00..183585.92 rows=3509192 width=313) (actual time=0.019..0.108 rows=334 loops=1)"
"        ->  Memoize  (cost=0.29..5.69 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=334)"
"              Cache Key: consumption.meter_id"
"              Cache Mode: logical"
"              Hits: 332  Misses: 2  Evictions: 0  Overflows: 0  Memory Usage: 1kB"
"              ->  Index Scan using ""PK_029a631471702a02287d44d1b44"" on devices  (cost=0.28..5.68 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=0 loops=2)"
"                    Index Cond: (id = device_usage.device_id)"
"                    Filter: ((organization_id = '******'::uuid) AND ((type)::text = 'water'::text))"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 0"
"Planning Time: 5.828 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.277 ms"

explian anlyze when using electricity:
"Limit  (cost=0.29..105.82 rows=10 width=313) (actual time=9846.837..9846.850 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..271814.00 rows=25758 width=313) (actual time=9846.831..9846.840 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on device_usage  (cost=0.00..183585.92 rows=3509192 width=313) (actual time=0.010..8359.976 rows=3509192 loops=1)"
"        ->  Memoize  (cost=0.29..5.69 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=3509192)"
"              Cache Key: device_usage.device_id"
"              Cache Mode: logical"
"              Hits: 3509104  Misses: 88  Evictions: 0  Overflows: 0  Memory Usage: 7kB"
"              ->  Index Scan using ""PK_029a631471702a02287d44d1b44"" on devices  (cost=0.28..5.68 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.161..0.161 rows=0 loops=88)"
"                    Index Cond: (id = device_usage.device_id)"
"                    Filter: ((organization_id = '******'::uuid) AND ((type)::text = 'electricity'::text))"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1"
"Planning Time: 2.794 ms"
"Execution Time: 9848.054 ms"


Can you show the output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE <query> for both cases?

Perhaps post the table generation script for both tables including any indexes.

Is type indexed? If not, the database has to search all the partial matches until it finds 10 matching rows.  The distribution of values matters too. If there are a lot of water devices and very few electricity devices, the first query will find 10 rows a lot faster than the second. I suspect you'd get different results if you used select count(*) instead of using limit 10, because that would have to find all results, not just the first 10.

@RichardHuxton updated the post

@PanagiotisKanavos the type column is indexed, but the number of electricity records are not very large.

Indexed how? What I see is an attempt to filter on the primary key: Index Scan using ""PK_029a631471702a02287d44d1b44"" on devices. The database is trying to first JOIN devices and device_usage and then filter. No index on organization_id or type is used. It's as if the database thinks the organization and type columns aren't selective enough. Please post the actual CREATE TABLE and any index creation commands. The best option would be an index on both organization_id and type, eg CREATE INDEX some_index ON device_usage (organization_id,type);

Add answers to following as text update to question: 1) This  10 records in 1 second and ... takes around 15 seconds to fetch the same number of records don't match the EXPLAIN output. 2) In the water query there is consumption.meter_id, I don't see that in the query. Are you using the same query in both cases? 3) Why index on device_usage.device_id  when you are filtering on devices.type?

It should not take over 8 seconds to scan 3.5 million rows.  You seem to have some serious issues going on with your machine, regardless of whether it is choosing the best plan or not.  Please include output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS), preferably with track_io_timing turned on.
